# How can I remove prefix with service name from logs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose inserts prefixes like `service_1           |` in the beginning of every line of output. I use this container for testing and this kind of improvement (very useful in other cases) mess my debugging logs and I want to remove it for this service. [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#logging) have no information about this question. Any ideas?
my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rds:
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  dynamo:
    image: iarruss/dynamo-local-admin:latest
    ports:
      - ${DYNAMODB_PORT}:8000
  python:
    container_name: python
    image: iarruss/docker-python2:latest
    depends_on:
      - rds
      - dynamo
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: rds
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      DYNAMODB_HOST: dynamo
```

**Edit:** Clarify expected result

Current output:

```
python             |
python             | collected 511 items
python             |
python             | tests/test_access.py
python             |
```

Expected output:

```
collected 511 items

test_access.py
```

Comment: How are you bringing up your containers? Are you explicitly setting the container name? Also, you mentioned service, are you using docker swarm?

Comment: @idjaw How are you bringing up your containers? `docker-compose up
` No swarm

Comment: You need to explicitly set the container name I believe in each of your service definitions. From the documentation you linked, it is specified in this section [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name)

Comment: @idjaw Excellent, your solution works. Thank you

Comment: @idjaw i'm wrong This changes affected only to the name of the prefix. I want to remove it completely. I added examples of current and expected output

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I want to keep my service names as is but when logging a specific service I am not interested in them at all.

Answer (score 12):

`docker compose logs` has a `--no-log-prefix` flag that removes the prefix.

For example

```
# start all services in background
docker compose up -d

# show logs for all services, without prefix (-f means follow the logs)
docker compose logs -f --no-log-prefix

# or, for a single service called foo
docker compose up foo -d
docker compose logs foo -f --no-log-prefix
```

[See the documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/#options)

Comment: Works for me, no need for sed magic, great answer! I find it peculiar that this option is missing from the logs doc page https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/logs/

Comment: What about docker stack? This does not work with `docker service logs` :/

Comment: what do you mean by docker stack, @xeruf?

Comment: I meant swarm mode, sorry.

Comment: Ah, in that case I don't know, sorry :-) Haven't used docker swarm. Might be worth posting as a separate question?

Answer (score 6):

In an unix shell you can use pipes (|):

```sh
docker-compose up python | sed -u 's/^[^|]*[^ ]* //'
```

The `[^|]*` means match everything that is not a |, so in your example it will match python and all spaces until the first |.

The `[^ ]*` is similar to the above, except that it matches everything that is not a space. This is necessary because there isn't only a space after the `|`, docker-compose adds some control characters to colorize output.

After this there is a space to actually remove the space after `|`.

The first slash of `//` determines the end of the first regular expression. Inside theses slash you can put some content to replace what was matched, in this case, it's empty.

The `-u` option is necessary when you use some other tools to manage your process, like [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a option for my case