# How run docker-compose without project-name?

Tags: docker-compose

By default, Compose bases the project name on basename of the directory compose commands are run from. The project name can be overridden either by passing a `-p / --project-name` option for each command or setting the `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable.

Can I run docker-compose with an empty project-name? I declare the volume with the name: myvolume and I would like to have the name `myvolume` after starting the container and not e.g. `user_myvolume`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have an empty project name as it's used internally by docker as part of the key for container.

It's discussed in more detail here: [Proposal: support for empty project names](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1621).

Comment: Sounds sensible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you want to remove the project name because it appears in your terminal, you can use [`--no-log-prefix`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855292/3130281).